# python version issues after ubuntu update to 22.04.1

Tags: apt, python, pip

I updated my ubuntu from 22.04 to 22.04.1 (jammy jellyfish), and I have been having some issues that I believe are related to python since. For example, whenever I try to install a python package I get

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'

This happens whenever I try to install a package on a project that is set with python 3.9 (The systems python version is set to 3.10).

I kind of just want to have the system reinstall and reconfigure all python versions and settings to whatever the default is. Is that possible? If not, is someone familiar with similar issues and can help?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. The system critically is relying on Python. Attempts to change the system wide installed python version will break your system.

To work with different versions of Python, you should set up [virtual environments](https://dev.to/bowmanjd/python-tools-for-managing-virtual-environments-3bko), that each can have their own Python version.